# Make gvim markdown highlight ignore internal markers

Tags: vim, escaping, markdown

I recently upgraded to gvim 7.3 and was pleased to find markdown highlighting. I also noticed that it treats "internal" `_`(underscore) as a marker. For example:

> *I want gvim to display emphasis here*
>
> but not_here

gvim actually displays the last line in my example as 'but not_*here*". It looks like SO's markdown interpretation is closer to what I want.

I do not say that gvim is "wrong" because I do not know what the correct markdown implementation is. However, is there a way to configure it so that the markers should be treated as normal text if they are surrounded by non-whitespace?

Comment: Which syntax file for markdown you're using (who wrote it)? There are multiple, and it will be easier to tell you how to modify them if we're know which file you're using.

Comment: How do I find that out? I am running gvim with the default settings.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I thought you installed the syntax file (and I didn't know Vim came with one for markdown :-o ) Well, go to Vim and `:e $VIMRUNTIME/syntax/markdown.vim`. Check what the header says, if it's by Tim Pope (Last Changed in 2010 May 21) then it's the same I have here

Comment: Thanks. I have the same `markdown.vim` file as yours.

Comment: You should change line 63 to fix this. You have the right syntax and vim is wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The runtime files (especially if you use the old Vim 7.3.000 / 046 installer found on vim.org) aren't updated frequently. Most plugin authors publish more recent releases elsewhere, and they are only occasionally picked up by Vim.

In [Tim Pope's repository](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown), you'll find a newer version (that you can install into your `~/.vim` directory) that doesn't show the problem; instead, it even highlights the single underscore character as an error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With the updated syntax file, the markdown highlighting works as expected.

Comment: I am afraid that is not true anymore in many cases https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown/issues/60

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution, which works in the things I have tested sofar.

Copy the `%vim%/syntax/markdown.vim` file into `%/.vim/syntax/markdown.vim` and change line 63  into:

```
syn region markdownItalic start="\s_\S\@=" end="\S\@<=_\|_\S\@=" keepend contains=markdownLineStart
```

Restart vim and it should match `*this*` and `_this_` but `not_this`.

EDIT: Changed information, thanks to @ZyX

Comment: Note: before changing anything copy file into `~/.vim/syntax/markdown.vim`. Don’t ever edit files within vim installation directory, any changes will be overwritten on update.

Comment: @WouterJ - would you mind explaining where %vim%/syntax/.. is?

Answer (score 2):

I had these issues when documenting code in markdown files.

The solution I used was to put the offending sections in a codeblock with four spaces or in a code span with surrounding back ticks (`).

Comment: And I had to use [tpope's markdown plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-markdown)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use Github flavor markdown: https://github.com/jtratner/vim-flavored-markdown